# Running docker on Ubuntu: mounted host volume is not writable from container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Docker works great on a Mac for me, but I have to run docker host inside of a VirtualBox (or Parallels, or VMWare Fusion), since Mac's kernel doesn't support docker.

So I tried to setup my application and a docker-compose on an Ubuntu Desktop - natively, where both docker client and docker host run physically on the same system. This worked, but my running docker containers can't write into a mounted host volume.

I use docker-compose with the following settings:

```
volumes:
   - ./api:/usr/src/app
```

So I'm mounting the "api" directory of the host Ubuntu OS into docker container under /usr/src/app.

`docker inspect <container ID>` shows that the volume is writable

```
"Destination": "/usr/src/app",
"Mode": "rw",
"RW": true
```

However it is not: I get `permission denied` when I try to create a directory or edit a file from within the docker container.

I googled for this issue, of course, and I came across a few SELinux issues of CentOS/RHEL, but **I'm running Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit edition**, not CentOS.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If your `uid` on the host (`id -u`) isn't the same as the `uid` of the user in the docker container (often "docker") then you can have this problem.  You can try:

1. Making the UIDs the same between your user and the user in the docker container.
2. Setting the group permissions on the directory to be writable for a group that both you and docker belong to.
3. You could also use the nuclear option:

`chmod a+rwx -R project-dir/`

The nuclear option will make your `git` workspace filthy, which will annoy you greatly, so isn't the best long-term solution.  It stops the bleeding tho.

For further understanding the problem, you might find these useful:

1. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7906
2. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198

Comment: Both "nuclear option" and uid fix worked. For uid fix I just added "usermod -u 1000 docker" to the Dockerfile.

Comment: In my case setting the owner on the volume directory to the user helped (UIDs were already the same).

Comment: but for me its not working after giving container uid:gid ownership to host dir.but if i mount  docker volume it works. Fails in case of `-v empty/dir:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-0.4.0`  but works fine  `-v volume_data:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-0.4.`

Comment: How do you do option 1?

Comment: "It stops the bleeding", but may open a whole new blackhole.

Answer (score 29):

### New answer:

This questions seems to have a lot of traffic and there is better solution available now -  [fixuid](https://github.com/boxboat/fixuid), as the name suggests it's a magic executable to change the container user's uid & gid on container startup (using -u somebody:somebody).

For a more in dept explanation see:
https://boxboat.com/2017/07/25/fixuid-change-docker-container-uid-gid/

---

### Old answer:

As of docker version 1.7 you have the option to mount a host directory with permissions to a container using the :Z or :z flags like so:

```
docker run -v ./api:/usr/src/app:Z
```

- :z - will add permissions to all containers using label 'svirt_sandbox_file_t'
- :Z - will add permissions only to the current container label

As of docker-compose v1.4.0, you can use it in docker compose like this:

```
volumes:
   - ./api:/usr/src/app:Z
```

Although I should add I still have some problems with this
(see [Adding permissions to host directory with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537168/adding-permissions-to-host-directory-with-docker-compose)).

References:

Using Volumes with Docker can Cause Problems with SELinux - http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/

Docker user guide -
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#volume-labels

Docker-compose release notes for v1.4.0 - https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.4.0

Comment: what is `svirt_sandbox_file_t`

Answer (score 0):

If your local config for the bind `/etc/named/named.conf.options` not contain the `directory "/var/..."` then it's probably try to put files into another directory without the server access. Add it to local config that will goes into container

*Note: it's applicable for specific bind9 docker container, don't forget to backup your config files first and make sure nothing important will be affected*