# Docker compose could not open directory permisson denied

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am totally a newbie when it comes to Docker. And I am trying to understand it with a dummy project. 
I have a django project and my `Dockerfile` is inside the Django project's root folder. And my `docker-compose.yml` file is under the top root folder which contains django project folder and other config files.

my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: dummy_project_postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  event_planner:
    build: ./dummy_project
    container_name: dummy_project
    volumes:
      - .:/web
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:postgres
```

and my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /web
WORKDIR /web
ADD requirements.txt /web/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /web/
```

I am trying to run the following commands

```
# stop and remove the existing containers
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm -f

# up and run the container
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d

docker-compose exec dummy_project bash
```

When I do `docker-compose up -d`, I see this error.

```
docker-compose up -d                                                                         
dummy_project_postgres is up-to-date
Starting dummy_project ... done
warning: could not open directory 'data/db/': Permission denied
```

I know this question asked before, but I didn't quite get the solution I need and I am stuck for hours now.

**EDIT:** I have all the permissions for all the folders under the top folder 
**EDIT2:** `sudo docker-compose up -d` also results the same error.

Comment: `sudo docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: I did, Still, Permission denied. @PetarP

Comment: On pycharm, there is a little lock icon on the data/db folder

Comment: Have you SELinux enabled? Try mount volume like this: `./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z` or `./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z` The z and Z volume flags are options for modifying selinux labels.

Comment: check if docker have sudo permissions, try playing in terminal first

Comment: Just tried. stopped containers, removed them built again and up -d again, same issue. I also tried to next step `docker-compose exec dummy_project bash` but it said `No container found for dummy_project_1` @RaoslawSzamszur

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to mount `./data/db` in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` and you're executing docker-compose with a **non-privileged** user.

So, we can have two possibilities:

1. Problem with ./data/db permissions.
2. Problem with /var/lib/postgresql/data

The simpiest solution is execute docker-compose with a privileged user (root), but if you don't want to do that, you can try this:

- Give permissions to ./data/db (I see your EDIT that you've already done it).
- Give permissions to /var/lib/postgresql/data

How can you give /var/lib/postgresql/data permissions? Read the following lines:

> First, note that /var/lib/postgresql/data is auto-generated by postgre
>   docker, so, you need to define a new Dockerfile which modifies these
>   permissions.  After that, you need also modify docker-compose to use
>   this new Dockerfile.

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build: 
      context: ./mypostgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_mypostgres
    container_name: dummy_project_postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  event_planner:
    build: ./dumy_project
    container_name: dummy_project
    volumes:
      - .:/web
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:postgres
```

**./dumy_project/Dockerfile** --> Without changes

**./mypostgres/Dockerfile_mypostgres**

```
FROM postgres
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/data
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/lib/postresql/data
ENTRYPOINT docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, 
in build, I get this 
`chmod: cannot access '/var/lib/postresql/data': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod -R 777 /var/lib/postresql/data' returned a non-zero code: 1`

but I didnt get this part, sorry; shouldn't the `var/lib/..` folder supposed to be inside the docker container?
We havent' create it yet but we are trying to change the permissions?

Comment: That's because /var/lib/postgresql/data might be created by the entrypoint, so, directory doesn't exist before postgresql execution. Let me edit my answer with directory creation.

Comment: okay this is strange, I can see that `Step 1/3 : FROM postgres` completed, `Step 2/3 : RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/data` completed using cache, when on `Step 3/3 : RUN chmod -R 777 /var/lib/postresql/data`, `chmod: cannot access '/var/lib/postresql/data': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod -R 777 /var/lib/postresql/data' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Answer (score 19):

I solved by adding ":z" to end of volume defintion

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: dummy_project_postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z

  event_planner:
    build: ./dummy_project
    container_name: dummy_project
    volumes:
      - .:/web
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:postgres
```

What ":z" means

> Labeling systems like SELinux require that proper labels are placed on
>   volume content mounted into a container. Without a label, the security
>   system might prevent the processes running inside the container from
>   using the content. By default, Docker does not change the labels set
>   by the OS.
>
> To change the label in the container context, you can add either of
>   two suffixes :z or :Z to the volume mount. These suffixes tell Docker
>   to relabel file objects on the shared volumes. The z option tells
>   Docker that two containers share the volume content. As a result,
>   Docker labels the content with a shared content label. Shared volume
>   labels allow all containers to read/write content. The Z option tells
>   Docker to label the content with a private unshared label. Only the
>   current container can use a private volume.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container---volumes-from

[what is 'z' flag in docker container's volumes-from option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218194/what-is-z-flag-in-docker-containers-volumes-from-option)

Comment: Thank you!
My problem was with SB 3.1.6 and 3.2.0, but it worked in 3.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for case that `your user` is not present in `docker` group.

1. First check if your user is in `docker` group:

```
grep 'docker' /etc/group
```

2. Add user to docker group:

- If the command return is empty, then create `docker` group:

```sh
sudo groupadd docker
```

- Else if your user is not present in command return then add him to the group:

```sh
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

3. Reboot your system
4. Test it again:

```sh
docker run hello-world
```

> Tip: Remember to have the docker service started

If it works, try your `docker-compose` command again.