# Docker container can't access mapped directory from host

Tags: linux, docker-compose, centos, grafana, influxdb

I'm running grafana and influxdb containers in a CentOS environment, but when I start the containers, both says that can't create the files on the mapped directories.

I have the same very environment running on Ubuntu with no troubles.

I have already chown'ed the directory to 472:472
I have mapped in docker-compose.yml the user Id of the owner (in ubuntu it solved the problem)
I'm running out of ideas!

Here is the command to start the containers

```
CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose -f /home/rastreamento/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Here is the yml for docker-composer that works fine on ubuntu:

```
version: '3'

services:
  grafana:
    image: "grafana/grafana"
    environment:
     - WORKING_DIR=/var/lib/grafana/working_dir
     - GF_SECURITY_DISABLE_GRAVATAR=true
     - GF_DEFAULT_INSTANCE_NAME=Valid
     - GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=200.166.40.21
     - GF_SERVER_ENFORCE_DOMAIN=false
     - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://200.166.40.21
     - GF_ANALYTICS_CHECK_FOR_UPDATES=false
     - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
     - GF_USERS_VIEWERS_CAN_EDIT=false
    ports:
     - "1982:3000"
    volumes:
     - /home/dev/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    links:
     - influxdb
    networks: 
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
     - influxdb
    user: ${CURRENT_UID}
  influxdb:
    image: "influxdb"
    environment:
     - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
     - INFLUXDB_DATA_MAX_SERIES_PER_DATABASE=0
     - INFLUXDB_DATA_MAX_VALUES_PER_TAG=0
    ports:
     - "8086:8086"
     - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
     - /home/dev/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
    networks: 
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    user: ${CURRENT_UID}
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
```

Here is one output from the container running Grafana.

> grafana_1   | mkdir: cannot create directory
>   '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': Permission denied

InfluxDB output:

> influxdb_1  | run: create server: mkdir all: mkdir
>   /var/lib/influxdb/meta: permission denied

I'm out of ideas now after 2 days of research to solve it.

thanks

**EDIT 1:**

As asked by Jan Garaj, the Docker information follows below:
*ps. I changed the wished host mapping to enable the container to run and access it's bash.*

*docker info*

```
[rastreamento@VMINDUS ~]$ docker info
Containers: 30
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 29
Images: 2
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: docker-runc runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
containerd version:  (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: 9c3c5f853ebf0ffac0d087e94daef462133b69c7 (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: fec3683b971d9c3ef73f284f176672c44b448662 (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
 selinux
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.666 GiB
Name: VMINDUS
ID: ZOZE:KEGT:SKTP:SG5J:3DKD:LCT3:STRW:FDO4:SFDP:FJJK:IAKQ:72DW
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

*Filesystem permissions*

```
[rastreamento@VMINDUS ~]$ ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 rastreamento docker 1221 Feb 11 15:05 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root         root      6 Feb 11 15:54 grafana
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root         root      6 Feb 11 15:54 influxdb
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 rastreamento docker  116 Feb 17 14:46 start_containers.sh
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 rastreamento docker   20 Feb 22  2019 stop_containers.sh
```

*ID from Grafana*

```
[rastreamento@VMINDUS ~]$ docker exec -it 691c907ed1f1 /bin/bash 
grafana@691c907ed1f1:/usr/share/grafana$ id 
uid=472(grafana) gid=472(grafana) groups=472(grafana)
```

For a matter of testing I started Grafana docker mapping the user to root and the directory /home/grafana as follows:

```
[rastreamento@VMINDUS ~]$ sudo docker run --user 0:0 -p 3000:3000 --volume /home/rastreamento/grafana:/home/grafana/ d0454da13c84
```

In the container shell I checked the id running the instance and tried to list the files in the /home/grafana directory

```
grafana@2263170898d0:/var/lib$ [rastreamento@VMINDUS ~]$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED    STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES 
345145c9a591        d0454da13c84        "/run.sh"           7 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   heuristic_wescoff 
[rastreamento@VMINDUS ~]$ docker exec -it 345145c9a591 /bin/bash
root@345145c9a591:/usr/share/grafana# cd /home/grafana/ 
root@345145c9a591:/home/grafana# ls 
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied 
root@345145c9a591:/home/grafana# id 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

As you can see, the user and group Ids seems to have been changed as it's supposed to be when the container was started, but even though, I can't get access to the host mapped directory.

Still no clues of why it works on Ubuntu but it doesn't in CentOs. I've never used CentOs, is there any other configuration to enable applications to access the host resources? Some security configuration? I'm really having a hard time with it.

Comment: Please provide your `docker info` and filesystem permission and userids from the container.

Comment: I've made some tests, but it's still not working. No clue at all. Added some edit on the text.

Comment: You are using 3 year old Docker version + custom sec comp profile `/etc/docker/seccomp.json`. Both of them can be a root cause.

Comment: Just solved it by adding a volume bind using ':z' after the volume. Thanks for the information, I'll update my docker from the original repo instead of using the package manager of CentOS. Probably this was the issue of the different behaviour between the two machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As assigned by Avi Farada in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031397/running-docker-on-ubuntu-mounted-host-volume-is-not-writable-from-container?rq=1), adding a volume bind solved my problem.

:z - will add permissions to all containers using label 'svirt_sandbox_file_t'
:Z - will add permissions only to the current container label

Just add to **docker run** ':z' like this:

```
docker run -v ./api:/usr/src/app:Z
```

or in my case, in **docker-composer**:

```
volumes:
   - ./api:/usr/src/app:Z
```

More information on this check the docker [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Another clever suggestion was addressed by Jan Garaj, and the different behaviour I had between the two machines was probably due to a version mismatch. I used the CentOS package manager to install docker, while in the other hand, on Ubuntu I downloaded the latest version from the official repo.

[ edit ]

**I used the Docker from the package repo of CentOS. That was completely outdated!!!**

On Docker official installation guide, the first thing they do is uninstall the stock docker on the machine, in case you've might done the same dumb thing I did.

Just install Docker by following the instructions on:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/